# Oracle hourly data view from event based hourly table

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, view

Hi i have a table which contain hourly LEND/RETURN transactions between multiple parties in an event based table as below:

```
FROM_CODE|TO_CODE|DAYTIME|TRAN_REASON|QTY

A, B, 08-OCT-2019 02:00, LEND, 100
A, B, 07-NOV-2019 04:00, LEND, 200
A, C, 20-JAN-2020 13:00, LEND, 400
B, A, 05-MAR-2020 20:00, RETURN, 150
C, A, 09-MAR-2020 23:00, RETURN, 200
C, A, 08-APR-2020 02:00, RETURN, 100
```

**Explanation:**

- A lent B 100 Qty on 08-OCT-2019 02:00,
- A lent B another 200 Qty on 07-NOV-2019 04:00,
- Then B return A 150 Qty on 05-MAR-2020 20:00..and
  etc.

**Question:**

How can i create a view from the table that could will give me result as below when i pass in pram date as shown in sample below:

1. If param date = 05-MAR-2020 21:00
   View will return me the transaction as per the hour before:

> ```
> DAYTIME|FROM_CODE|TO_CODE|TRAN_REASON|QTY
>
> 05-MAR-2020 21:00, A, B, LEND, 300
> 05-MAR-2020 21:00, B, A, RETURN, 150
> 05-MAR-2020 21:00, A, C, LEND, 400
> ```

2. If param date = 10-MAR-2020 00:00

> ```
> DAYTIME|FROM_CODE|TO_CODE|TRAN_REASON|QTY
>
> 10-MAR-2020 00:00, A, B, LEND, 300
> 10-MAR-2020 00:00, B, A, RETURN, 150
> 10-MAR-2020 00:00, A, C, LEND, 400
> 10-MAR-2020 00:00, C, A, RETURN, 200
> ```

3. If param date = 20-JUN-2020 00:00

> ```
> DAYTIME|FROM_CODE|TO_CODE|TRAN_REASON|QTY
>
> 20-JUN-2020 00:00, A, B, LEND, 300  
> 20-JUN-2020 00:00, B, A, RETURN, 150 
> 20-JUN-2020 00:00, A, C, LEND, 400 
> 20-JUN-2020 00:00, C, A, RETURN, 300
> ```

Note:

1. Param date would not match exactly the daytime in table
2. Result will show the status of transaction as per the previous hour

The reason for having the hourly data view is because currently we are relying on a legacy system that could only 'read' static data for reporting purpose, the valid from/until approach cannot be used :(
Appreciated help from anyone that could help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Do you really need PARAM date? Or we can use current datetime, ie trunc(sysdate,'hh') is ok for you too?

Comment: How do you pass PARAM to ' read static data'?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create view that returns input variables as a column value, but you have 2 options to get what you want:

a) Use simple query: `:dt` here is you input bind variable

```
with t(FROM_CODE,TO_CODE,DAYTIME,TRAN_REASON,QTY) as (
select 'A', 'B', to_date('08-OCT-2019 02:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'LEND', 100   from dual union all
select 'A', 'B', to_date('07-NOV-2019 04:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'LEND', 200   from dual union all
select 'A', 'C', to_date('20-JAN-2020 13:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'LEND', 400   from dual union all
select 'B', 'A', to_date('05-MAR-2020 20:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'RETURN', 150 from dual union all
select 'C', 'A', to_date('09-MAR-2020 23:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'RETURN', 200 from dual union all
select 'C', 'A', to_date('08-APR-2020 02:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'RETURN', 100 from dual 
)
select
   FROM_CODE,
   TO_CODE,
   :dt, 
   TRAN_REASON,
   sum(qty)
from t
where daytime<=:dt
group by
   FROM_CODE,
   TO_CODE,
   TRAN_REASON
```

b) use pipelined function with the same query:
Full example:

```
create table test_data as
with t(FROM_CODE,TO_CODE,DAYTIME,TRAN_REASON,QTY) as (
   select 'A', 'B', to_date('08-OCT-2019 02:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'LEND', 100   from dual union all
   select 'A', 'B', to_date('07-NOV-2019 04:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'LEND', 200   from dual union all
   select 'A', 'C', to_date('20-JAN-2020 13:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'LEND', 400   from dual union all
   select 'B', 'A', to_date('05-MAR-2020 20:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'RETURN', 150 from dual union all
   select 'C', 'A', to_date('09-MAR-2020 23:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'RETURN', 200 from dual union all
   select 'C', 'A', to_date('08-APR-2020 02:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'RETURN', 100 from dual 
)
select *
from t
/
create or replace package pkg_test as
   type t_test_data_row is record (
      DAYTIME      test_data.DAYTIME%type,
      FROM_CODE    test_data.FROM_CODE%type,
      TO_CODE      test_data.TO_CODE%type,
      TRAN_REASON  test_data.TRAN_REASON%type,
      QTY          test_data.QTY%type
   );
   type t_test_data_tab is table of t_test_data_row;

  function get_output (dt date) return t_test_data_tab pipelined;
end;
/
create or replace package body pkg_test as

  function get_output (dt date) return t_test_data_tab pipelined
  is
  begin
     for r in (
         select
            get_output.dt,
            FROM_CODE,
            TO_CODE,
            TRAN_REASON,
            sum(qty) as qty
         from test_data
         where daytime<=get_output.dt
         group by
            FROM_CODE,
            TO_CODE,
            TRAN_REASON
     )
     loop
        pipe row (r);
     end loop;
  end;
end;
/
select * 
from table(pkg_test.get_output(to_date('2020-03-05 21:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')));
```

Result:

```
DAYTIME             F T TRAN_R        QTY
------------------- - - ------ ----------
2020-03-05 21:00:00 A B LEND          300
2020-03-05 21:00:00 B A RETURN        150
2020-03-05 21:00:00 A C LEND          400
```